# Excel OLEDB reading valid values as DBNull

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbdatareader

I have an excel file that has a row of double values. It validates the first 8 rows correctly but if there is bad data in row 9 or higher then it sees the datatype as a dbnull instead of a double.

For example if my column looks like this (3 rows):

```
1234.22
1234.55
5555.xyz
```

This will see row 3 as a double and also that row 3 has alpha numeric characters

However if I do it like this (over 9 rows):

```
1234
12345
12346
4357676
3456787
3456567
234234
978978
76867.ddd
123942
```

Then it will see the second to last row as a dbNull with a cell value of " ". But it will see the very last row as double again with its correct cell value.

This is my connection string so I am using Imex = 1

```
string connString = connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;'";
```

After further investigation it is this that is causing the issue 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel] located registry REG_DWORD "TypeGuessRows" I found. It is defaulted to 8 in the registry.

Apparently this reads only the first 8 rows. I need to be able to scan all rows.

There is no way for me to set this in code? I cannot modify the registry at work

Comment: Use : HDR=No.  You are reading the headers as data.

Comment: The HDR is correct. Its the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel] located registry REG_DWORD "TypeGuessRows" I found. There is no way for me to set this in code? I cannot modify the registry at work

Comment: What do you want to do exactly. Why is having a DbNull value a problem?

Comment: @Maxter we validate what the user puts in an excel file before we display or upload any data. If the user enters in data and excel sees it as dbnull with a value of empty string then that is a problem

Comment: Can't you do a simple check in your C# code like this:
If field is DbNull then...

Comment: You cant unless you modify that registry setting. Theres no implemented way period, the only option is scanning every column/row and then validate it. Even if you change the registry that can have huge performance issues...

Comment: Can you convert all excel data format to string before doing your query (using excel interop for exemple)?